# OLS estimation for ornstein uhlenbeck process

Tags: backtesting, simulations, quants, ornstein-uhlenbeck

I am reading the following [paper](https://deliverypdf.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=691097078009123084113078076028101005040037066015093025096085109069090114029002100121124061122043062030037029004127000067018002110055002081003094027083088004011100008036009084068092028076090073064081084121119118102024027000110064104074106115096085005&EXT=pdf&INDEX=TRUE). In particular, in section 4 - numerical determination of OTRs, it mentions applying Ordinary Least Square on Eq(5). However, what I don't know is whether ${P_{0,0}, P_{0,1}, ...,P_{0,T_1}}$ is simulated or coming from actual historical data? I am guessing it's coming from actual historical data because we need to first estimate the parameters then generate simulated price series.

Furthermore, where do I get the forecasted prices ${E_0[P_{0,T_0}], ..., E_0[P_{1,T_1}]}$? Am I suppose to predict them from my own strategy? What if my strategy only predicts direction but not actual price movement?